# Migrating from EF5 to EF6: InversePropertyAttribute broken?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a class setup similar to the code below.

```
public abstract class Record<T>
where T : class
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long MasterId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MasterId")]
    public virtual T Master { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Master")]
    public virtual ICollection<T> Suggestions { get; set; }
}
```

This allows me to create classes like below with minimal boilerplate code that can have "suggestions" - minor changes that are then merged in when approved.

```
public class Concrete : Record<Concrete>
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

In EF5, this used to work flawlessly. However, I am now getting the below error message at *runtime*:

> The entity type 'Foo.Models.Concrete' to which the navigation property
>   'Suggestions' 
>   refers is not the same as the type 'Foo.Models.Record`1[[Foo.Models.Concrete, Foo,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' on which the inverse 
>       navigation property 'Master' is declared.

Is there any way to fix this issue, or is there a better design structure that I could be using to tackle this problem?

Comment: This issue was logged in the EF bug tracking system here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1792 it looks like the fix will make it into the 6.0.2 release

Comment: The fix for this bug made it into the last nights nightly build, could you please check to make sure your scenario is fixed? Instructions for using the nightly feed are here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nightly%20Builds, to get the build that has this fix you can run the following command from the package manager console: "Install-package EntityFramework -pre -version 6.0.2-nightly-21118"